# Restrict users to see detailview based on model field value in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am learning and have a change management project where my model contains field `confidential` which is by default `False`, however during instance creation so called `initiator` could tick it as `True`. This basically means that only users which are part of current record so called `signees` could open and see the instance. I am trying to apply get_queryset override on my DetailView:

```
# MOC DetailView 

class MocDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Moc
    template_name = 'moc/moc_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        

        for obj in qs:
            print(obj)
            confidential = obj.confidential
            

            initiator = obj.initiator
            coordinators = obj.coordinators.all()
            reviewers = obj.reviewers.all()
            approvers = obj.approvers.all()
            preimplements = obj.preimplements.all()
            authorizers = obj.authorizers.all()
            postimplements = obj.postimplements.all()
            closers = obj.closers.all()

           

            if initiator and initiator == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                

                qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(initiator=self.request.user))
               
                return qs

       

            for signee in coordinators:
                coordinator_name = signee.coordinator_name
            
                if coordinator_name and coordinator_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(coordinators__coordinator_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs
                
            for signee in reviewers:
                reviewer_name = signee.reviewer_name
                if reviewer_name and reviewer_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(reviewers__reviewer_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs

            for signee in approvers:
                approver_name = signee.approver_name
                if approver_name and approver_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(approvers__approver_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs

            for signee in preimplements:
                actionee_name = signee.actionee_name
                if actionee_name and actionee_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(preimplements__actionee_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs

            for signee in authorizers:
                authorizer_name = signee.authorizer_name
                if authorizer_name and authorizer_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(authorizers__authorizer_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs

            for signee in postimplements:
                actionee_name = signee.actionee_name
                if actionee_name and actionee_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(postimplements__actionee_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs

            for signee in closers:
                closer_name = signee.closer_name
                if closer_name and closer_name == self.request.user and confidential == True:
                    qs = qs.filter(Q(confidential=True) & Q(closers__closer_name=self.request.user))
                    
                    return qs
```

This allows to restrict Users only to those who are my `signees`, but in case my `confidential` field is `False` non of them are able to open those model instances.

Is there any where I introduce logic here to allow straight opening of non confidential model instance?

Appreciate your help...

**Update**

```
# MOC model

class Moc(models.Model):
    moc_status = FSMField(choices=STATES, default='draft', protected=False)
    initiator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, related_name='area_moc', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category_moc', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    confidential = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Verifier model

class Verifier(models.Model):
    moc = models.ForeignKey(Moc, related_name='verifiers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    verifier_group = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)    
    verifier_name = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)    
    verify_due = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

# Coordinator model

class Coordinator(models.Model):
    moc = models.ForeignKey(Moc, related_name='coordinators', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    cooridnator_group = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)    
    coordinator_name = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)    
    coordinator_due = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

..... so on so forth for all above listed signees.....

Comment: This won't fix your issue (probably), but you don't need to use `Q()` here. You can simplify your queries by doiong `qs.filter(confidential=True, initiator=self.request.user)` for all `AND` type queries.

Comment: Another side note: `confidential == True` in your `if` conditions can be simplified to just `confidential`.

Comment: Is the `return qs` in each for loop intentional? This will return immediately and won't execute any later iterations of that loop or any other loops.

Comment: The manual `for obj in qs` is probably not the correct way to do what you want. Even if it does, this is always slower than writing a correct `qs.filter()` that allows the database to optimize the query.

Comment: Will you describe in words what the business rules are for this route? The code you show is much more complicated than I originally assumed from your question. I think there are some missing details that would help me give a good answer to your question.

Comment: Also, will you [edit] your question to show the code for the relevant models?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Thank you for your comments. I will apply 1st and 2nd suggestions.

Comment: Feel free to ping me with answers to my questions and when you add the requested model code.

Comment: I will do, I just need to figure my answers...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Answer on 4th Q:  I have 1 to M relationships between my `Moc` and so called signee models i.e. (`coordinator, verifier, reviewer, approver ...`), hence I am getting not object but object list i.e. moc.coordinators.all(). In order to check whether there is user in the list I have to iterate it (this is my understanding...). Consequently, I am not worrying about breaking the further iterations once first one executes and further logic proves i.e.  coordinator_name == self.request.user means that user which is logged in and trying to open instance is related with model instance.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I have provided my comment and updated my question with models. Appreciate your help!

Comment: "In order to check whether there is user in the list I have to iterate it (this is my understanding...)" You should write a `filter()` query that does this iteration for you on the database side. It will be significantly more efficient for a high number of rows in each table. For help with writing that query, I will need more details about the exact business logic. I mean what are the exact rules involved here?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, thanks for your comment, although I am not getting the point 'write a filter() query that does this iteration for you on the database side' and what impact it might have in overall on the app, my detailview logic requires restrict the users to see Moc record if they are not related to it through respective foreignkey relation described in my models. As I mentioned this is achieved by my logic above (of course I accept that it maybe not elegant, but it does the purpose.).

Comment: I am expecting to have in total approx. 20 rows in sum for all related models instances against Moc instance so from efficiency point of view I really don't get the point (as I know because of the of querysets are lazy, I shall not be loading memory while I am keeping them in the logic). Also thing is that confidential == True is rear case and I do not expect this particular logic will be utilized excessively while what I do require i.e. for confidential == False all users shall be able to open Moc instances.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, can you please tell me if you can help on this? If not - thanks anyway for your suggestions!

Comment: I'm still unclear about the rules about which objects a particular user is able to view. If you still need help, will you explain these rules in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by the following code modification:

```
class MocDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
model = Moc
template_name = 'moc/moc_detail.html'
context_object_name = 'moc'

def get_object(self, queryset=None):

    obj = super(MocDetailView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)

    print(obj)

    confidential = obj.confidential
    initiator = obj.initiator

    # verifiers = obj.verifiers.all()
    verifier = obj.verifiers.filter(verifier_name=self.request.user)
    print(verifier)
    # coordinators = obj.coordinators.all()
    coordinator = obj.coordinators.filter(coordinator_name=self.request.user)
    print(coordinator)
    # reviewers = obj.reviewers.all()
    reviewer = obj.reviewers.filter(reviewer_name=self.request.user)
    print(reviewer)
    # approvers = obj.approvers.all()
    approver = obj.approvers.filter(approver_name=self.request.user)
    print(approver)
    # preimplements = obj.preimplements.all()
    preimplement = obj.preimplements.filter(actionee_name=self.request.user)
    print(preimplement)
    # authorizers = obj.authorizers.all()
    authorizer = obj.authorizers.filter(authorizer_name=self.request.user)
    print(authorizer)
    # postimplements = obj.postimplements.all()
    postimplement = obj.postimplements.filter(actionee_name=self.request.user)
    print(postimplement)
    # closers = obj.closers.all()
    closer = obj.closers.filter(closer_name=self.request.user)
    print(closer)

    if self.request.user.is_superuser or initiator == self.request.user or verifier or coordinator or reviewer or approver or preimplement or authorizer or postimplement or closer and confidential == True:
        return obj

    
    elif not confidential:
        return obj      

    else:
        raise Http404()
```

Comment: Here you are overriding `get_object()` but your question, you were overriding `get_queryset()`. These methods do two different things.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yeah, as I stated I modified my original logic from get_queryset to get_object and I achieved what I wanted... As I said I am not an expert in programming and sometimes I am not sure if my approaches are correct/efficient but at least this struggles allow me to become more knowledgeable in this field... I tried to use queryset filtering as you suggested and now it works fine in my new logic. Thanks for that and glad that I learned something new from your side too!